# Meaning of Gauss Law

Tags: electromagnetism

When a charge \$Q\$ is considered and in order to apply [Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law), we take a spherical Gaussian surface, obviously we get, \$D\ = Q/(4 \pi r^2)\$ My question is, as we go extremely close to the center, the expression would give extremely large value of D - what does this mean physically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*as radius tends to zero, the expression would give infinity*

This is not correct. That a limit is defined does not mean that an expression is defined at the limit. In fact, when the limit is a real number (like 0), why would we even need limits, were this not so?

The ordinary limit of this expression is not defined:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2} = \text{undefined}$$

See [division by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#In_calculus).

However, the [one sided limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) is defined:

$$ \lim_{r \searrow 0} \frac{Q}{4\pi r^2} = \infty $$

but this still does not mean you can do this:

$$\require{cancel} \cancel{\frac{Q}{4\pi0^2} = \infty} $$

*Why do we get infinite field at center?*

You don't. The one-sided limit means \$D\$ can be made arbitrarily large by making \$r\$ arbitrarily small *but not zero*. When \$r=0\$, \$D\$ is undefined, any way you slice it. Using a limit doesn't make dividing by zero defined.

There is a reason \$D\$ is undefined when \$r=0\$: two things can not occupy the same space at the same time. As some other like charge approaches the charge at the center of your sphere, it experiences an increasing repulsive force. There is no limit to how large this force can become, so you can never get the two charges in the same space.

Two things can happen, if you try. The common case is that the charges approach each other until the repulsive force grows to be sufficient to balance whatever other force is pushing the charges closer. This is what prevents you from pushing your finger through the desk, for example.

The less common case is that you get close enough that [other forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction) become significant, and your charge at the center can no longer be considered a point, but must be considered as separate, more [fundamental particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_particle). This usually doesn't happen because it requires so much energy. At this point, probably you are playing with a particle accelerator, and you have exited the field of electrical engineering and entered the field of particle physics. I'm not a physicist so I can't tell you exactly what will happen, other than it will look something like this:

[image: simulated Higgs boson]

I really have no idea what this picture represents, other than whatever was in the middle blew up. I've yet to observe such effects in my circuits, so I haven't had reason to care :)

Comment: Also, even if you are taking r to zero, I think the limit is pretty well defined. If we are talking about a radius, we are talking about approaching zero from the positive side.

Comment: @ThePhoton sure, the one-sided limit is defined, but that doesn't mean the expression is defined at the limit, and this is the flaw in the question. Hope edits make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

At the imaginary surface defined by the sphere of radius r, the displacement field is defined by that equation through the application of Gauss's law and using the surface area of a sphere.  Gauss's law says that the net flux through the surface is proportional to the charge enclosed by the surface, clearly when r=0 the surface does not enclose any volume and Gauss's law does not hold.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for reminding me the exact statement. But, does the meaning of surface enclosing volume imply that - for calculation of electric field we need another test charge with respect to which it is calculated?

Comment: No a test charge is not necessary, the displacement field exists because the charge exists.  The field lines terminate at infinity.

Answer (score 2):

> What does this mean physically?

Let's look at the assumption that lead to this result.

- There is a *point charge*, \$Q\$, at the origin of our coordinate
  system.

Now, this means that the charge density associated with this point charge is:

\$\rho(r) = \delta(r) \$

In other words, the charge density is *zero* except at the origin where it is "infinite" in such a way that the total charge is *Q*.

How *physical* is this assumption?

If you're of the conviction that there are no *actual* infinities, then it is clear how to proceed:  represent the charge density as function that goes to a \$\delta\$ in some limit.  For example:

\$\rho(r) = \begin{cases} \frac{3Q}{4\pi R^3}, & r \le R \\ 0, & r > R \end{cases}\$

Now, we can make \$R\$ arbitrarily small such that the charge is *effectively* a point charge but now, \$D\ = Q/(4 \pi r^2)\$ only holds for \$r > R\$, i.e., \$D \$ no longer diverges at the origin.

Comment: But, isn't this expression of rho true for charge Q to be distributed over entire volume i.e., volume charge density only?

Comment: @Enthusiast, the charge is not distributed over the *entire* volume.  The charge is contained within a spherical volume, centered on the origin, of radius R.  The charge density is zero outside of this.